# Multiple boolean tests in IF statement with 'all()' function

Tags: python, function, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

```
def common(num):
    #returns true if num is divisible by all the 'i' integers

    if all(num%divisor==0 for divisor in (1,10)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(common(2520)) --> True
print(common(10))   --> True
print(common(17))   --> False
```

Hi all, this function is supposed to tell whether 'num' is a common multiple of all the 'i' numbers. I can't figure out why 10 is returning True? Doesn't 'all()' mean every test has to be True for the whole thing to be True?
Am I using it wrong? Any better functions I should use? Thanks for any insights.

-wT

Comment: The only values bound to `divisor` are 1 and 10.  Just those two.  It's unclear what you _intended_ to do.  Maybe you wanted, e.g., `range(1, 10)`?  Can't guess.

Comment: Or perhaps `range(1, 11)`

Comment: Just FYI, if you find yourself doing `if condition: return True; else: return False`, you can in fact just do `return condition`. (In some situations, Python will convert things to boolean values for an `if` statement, so if you want to be super diligent, do `return bool(condition)`.)

Comment: BTW the `if` / `else` is not necessary. Just return the result of the `all()` call.

Answer (score 3):

The way to find oneself:

```
num=10
for divisor in (1,10):
    print(divisor, num%divisor , num%divisor==0)
```

gives

```
1 0 True
10 0 True
```

and makes you understand that `(1,10)` is a tuple, while you certainly wanted `range(1,10)`.

Note that the function `common()` has the same return values as

```
 all(num%divisor==0 for divisor in range(1,10))
```

then you can define it as:

```
def common(num):
    return all(num%divisor==0 for divisor in range(1,10))
```

Comment: @John OK. I just upvoted your most upvoted answer as a thanking

Comment: Thanks John! I'm new to programming/python so I didn't know what a tuple was. And I see what you mean about ditching the if statement. You rock!